# Apply function on rows to extract col names (not values) in r

Tags: r

I have the following

```
 mat <- structure(c(56L, 45L, 64L, 43L, 67L, 17L, 164L, 158L, 150L,177L,111L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 10L), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("Bob", "Sam", "Bill", "Mary", "Ted"), c("X1", "X2", "X3"
)))
```

I used this to sort by row:

```
 apply(mat, 1, sort)
```

However, instead of getting the VALUES, I would like the column names.  Is this possible?  The output would need to look this this:

```
 mat.res <- structure(c("X2", "X1", "X3", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2",  "X3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2"), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("Bob", "Sam", "Bill", "Mary", "Ted")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
apply(mat,1,function(x){names(sort(x))})
```